# How to get a correct group in my geopandas project?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, geopandas

I'm making a project which find the nearest linestring(simulate a river) to points or a single point,looks like this:

```
linestrings  points
linestring1  point1    
linestring2  point4     
linestring1  point2    
linestring2  point5
linestring1  point3    
linestring2  point6
```

And it looks like this in intellij idea:
[image]

I want to group the dataframe by linestrings to insert points,like this:

```
linestrings  points
linestring1  point1    
linestring1  point2   
linestring1  point3    
linestring2  point4
linestring2  point5   
linestring2  point6
```

So that I can snap linestring1 to point 1,2,3 and so on.

Look at this picture,the same linestring should be snapped on 3 points:
[image: image of joined geodataframe]

However when I launch my code,I can only see dtypes in form of DataFrame:

[image]

And group look like this：

[image]

It's obvious that my effort is failed，and in pandas'document,a correct group should looks like this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby

So what's my problem and how I can solve it?

This is a part of my code:

```
list_point_line_tuple = []
    for point in gpd_nodes_df.geometry:
        list_point_line_tuple.append((point.to_wkt(), geopandas_min_dist(point, gpd_network_df, 200).geometry.to_wkt()))
    graph_frame = gpd.GeoDataFrame(list_point_line_tuple, columns=['near_stations', 'nearest_line'])
    grouped_graph_frame = graph_frame.groupby('nearest_line', as_index=False)
```

And all code is here: https://github.com/forestbat/stream-simulate-conda

Comment: [please do not post images of code, data, or errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, include them as [formatted text blocks](/help/formatting). Whenever possible, try to generate small data examples using code to form a [mre]. But even if you are asking about existing data structures, paste the result of `print(df)` as a code block rather than posting an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't group on geometries at all. they're not hashable and can't be used as a pandas index. instead, use geopandas' spatial join tools, such as [`geopandas.sjoin_nearest`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html):

```py
merged = geopandas.sjoin_nearest(points_geodataframe, lines_geodataframe, how='left')
```

See the geopandas [docs on spatial joins](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html) for more info.